# Japan character - bytes length

Tags: java, character-encoding

Length of japan character, is different from length of US character.

Example:

```
String str = new String("アサヒコ");
int numBytes = str.getBytes().length;   12 

for Us:
String str = new String("san");
int numBytes = str.getBytes().length;   3
```

How should i get the JAPAN bytes length exact same way of US character.

For single JAPAN character , why it is giving 2 bytes , some times it is giving 3 bytes for single JAPAN character.

Please tell me how should i get the bytes value for JAPAN character in java

Comment: Kanji and English use two different alphabets, with two different encodings.  A character can be one, two, or even four bytes, depending on the encoding, so what you are seeing is to be expected actually.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Same encoding in the Java `String`: UTF-16.

Answer (score 5):

What [`getBytes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) called with no arguments returns will depend on your system. From that documentation:

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.

So for instance, if your system's default encoding is UTF-8, it may well take four bytes to encode a single Japanese character, but will typically take only one byte to encode a single U.S. English alphabetic character. More in [the Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

There are overloads of `getBytes` that let you specify what encoding to use.

More background:

Java's strings are [represented using UTF-16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1) (which is why Java can use the whole of Unicode even though `char` is only 16 bits wide). In UTF-16, multiple `char`s may be needed to represent one "character" (in Unicode parlance, multiple code units may be needed to represent a code point). If you want to access the number of *code points* in a string, you can use [`codePointCount`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointCount-int-int-); to access the code points, you can use the [`codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePoints--) stream. [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) has a couple of other code-point-related methods as well, just search the JavaDoc for "codepoint".

All that is related to `String`, specifically; once you convert to a byte array, you're potentially using an encoding other than UTF-16.

Comment: Misunderstood the question at first, hopefully have fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

[Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(computing)) is not a well defined concept.  But usually you can count unicode codepoints.

Simple but heavy overhead (Java 9+):

```
"アサヒコ".codePoints().count() // 4
```

Old school but more efficient (Java 1.5+):

```
String mbtext = "アサヒコ";
int characterCount = mbtext.codePointCount( 0, mbtext.length() );
// characterCount = 4
```

This works on most text - English, French, CJK (Chinese, Japanes, Korean), Arabic, you name it.

Sometimes there will be [modifier characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakuten_and_handakuten) or other non-printables, that will be counted individually this way. You can remove them to get the "visual" character count  (Java 7+):

```
"か゚き゚く゚け゚こ゚\r\n".replaceAll( "[\\p{M}\\p{C}]+", "" ).codePoints().count() // 5
```

> `\p{M}` strips marks, `\p{C}` strips line breaks and tabs. To remove spaces, use `\p{Z}`